# how to get return value from java class to servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

hi can i know how to pass return value from normal java class to servlet then display it using jsp? i tried but only got null value.

Result.java

```
package langID; 

public class Result {

public String Show()
{

    return "result";

}
}
```

Formhandler.java (servlet)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("comment.jsp");    
Result demo = new Result();
String s = demo.Show();
request.setAttribute("s", s);  
rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

comment.jsp

```
<%String name = (String)request.getAttribute("s"); %>
                    <%= s%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the jsp that you have to write :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:useBean id="s" scope="request" class="java.lang.String"></jsp:useBean>
<%=s %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user2297643 Vote for the answer when you get minimum reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Here you   need to use   `<%= name%>`  not `<%= s%>`

Because your value is now available in `name` not in `s`

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/comment.jsp?
 valpass=val");


 Result demo = new Result();
         String s = demo.Show();
          request.setAttribute("s", s);  
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: <%String name = (String)request.getAttribute("s"); %>
 <%= name%>

Comment: why you used rd.forward here

Comment: You could set all the values into the response object before forwaring the request to the jsp. Or you can put your values into a session bean and access it in the

Comment: see here http://www.coderanch.com/t/445845/JSP/java/request-getAttribute-returns-null-jsp.It might help you